# Best way to locate a 4k stray resistance between 2 bus lines in a PCB?

Tags: pcb, troubleshooting, fault

I have a faulty PCB which is showing an unexpectedly low resistance between certain pairs of bus address lines.  I'm measuring a little over 4k ohms between these bus lines, but according to the schematic I should be seeing 44k.

I'd like to try to isolate the fault down to a particular IC or area of the PCB.  None of the ICs are socketed, so I'd like to have some idea of where the fault is before I start lifting pins.

I've heard of using a milliohm meter to find shorts in PCBs, measuring resistance between various points and looking for a minimum.  But unfortunately as I mentioned above, this fault is about 4k.  I'd be looking for a tens of milliohms change in R relative to 4k (roughly 1 part in 100000), and I don't have a high-enough resolution meter to detect that (all I have is a 3 1/2 digit meter).

What would be the most promising direction to take for isolating a fault such as this?  I'm thinking something along the lines of a wheatstone bridge + instrumentation amp, but maybe there's a better technique?

Comment: Are you sure the resistance you're measuring isn't from the ICs on the bus?

Comment: Check the 44k's aren't 4.4k

Comment: Before starting to lift pins, wash the board thoroughly in clean isopropyl alcohol or in flux removing solvent, and dry/bake it.

Comment: Yes, to re-iterate what Tony said, this could very well be a misload. Presumably the 44k you are expecting is caused by a 44k resistor, or a few resistors in series. If the 44k or several series resistors are the wrong value (off by a factor of 10 is easy to do!) then you may be seeing 4.4k instead of 44k.

Comment: Does the board work? Do you have more than one board, and are they all like this? Resistances can be unpredictable for a lot of reasons. It is best to compare with a known good board if possible.

Comment: @immibis, I do suspect that the problem is probably with one of the ICs, since a visual inspection of the board showed nothing obvious.  I'm hoping to minimize the amount of pin lifting, if I can use some method to isolate the fault.

Comment: @mkeith, each of the bus lines is pulled up with a 22k resistor, and between most of the pairs of bus lines, I'm seeing 44k total.  It's only  when I include BUS 7 in the measurement that I'm seeing 4.19k.  But it's a good suggestion to check the resistor values; I'll do that as soon as I can.  The board is partially working, but code execution eventually crashes.  Unfortunately, this is the only board I have!

Comment: @AliChen, thanks for the suggestion.  I'll try washing the board and seeing if the stray resistance value changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I do it is remove the pins attached to the bus one by one (or all at once) until the offending part is found (and in your case the resistance would go back up to 44k). This can be done by unsoldering a pin and then lifting it up carefully. SMT parts will have to be lifted completely. Try to rule out the easiest parts first.

Another way I have done this in the past to find power problems (a short is similar to yours)  is to cut a trace (which may not work so well for high speed signals( 10Mhz+), but works great for power an low speed signals. I usually cut the trace to cut the traces attached to the net in half, and then test the two halves. Once the offending part is found it can be replaced.

A hi res IR camera might be sensitive enough to detect a temperature change of the offending part if you have a board to compare this to.

Comment: I am afraid I may have to start doing exactly what you suggested (after checking the resistor values and washing the board).  The reason I'm hesitant to lift pins is that my faulty board is a "classic" COSMAC VIP microcomputer from the 70s.  I'd like to lift as few pins as possible, so I was hoping to somehow "ohm out" the general location of the fault first.

Comment: Any thoughts on the utility of a wheatstone bridge + instrumentation amp?  It seems that the difficulty is: instead of a short somewhere, I've got a stray 4.19k.  Looking for changes of resistance on the order of 1 part in 100000 might be tricky, even with some sort of bridge/amp circuit.

Comment: The time it would take to do this would be more than that of pulling pins, you have to replace a chip anyway, that is the way I would look at it.

Comment: UPDATE: PROBLEM RESOLVED!

After a long hiatus from this project, I finally found the time to dig into it again and have solved the problem.

The board is an old RCA COSMAC VIP 711 microcomputer. It's a 4K system, with a total of eight 2114 DRAMs. Six of these are socketed, and two are not. Here's a summary of the steps I took to solve the problem...

Comment: 1. Performed visual inspect of all bus traces. Only suspicious thing I found was some gummy flux.
2. Washed the board with isopropyl alcohol, removing the flux. No improvement.
3. Removed the six socketed DRAMs. No improvement.
4. Removed the first unsocketed DRAM (destructive). No improvement.
5. Removed the second unsocketed DRAM (destructive). STRAY RESISTANCE RESOLVED!

Comment: 6. Installed two new replacement DRAMs. Board passed extended memory test.
7. Reinstalled the six socketed DRAMs. Board FAILED extended memory test.
8. Added additional decoupling caps since the original board only had two caps for entire 4K of DRAM. Board PASSED extended memory text.
SUMMARY: Apparently, the stray resistance was due to a faulty DRAM (about 40 years old). The faulty DRAM continued to operate, but would occasionally fail. I suspect that the replacement DRAMs (recently manufactured 2114 chips) were more susceptible to noise than the original parts, and needed more decoupling.